# What is the best way to go about storing variables in the cloud?

Tags: javascript, project

As a fun little project I am going to try and make a toy crypto currency. I can make around 1/2 of this project right now, but I need to know how to store data on the server, from js (i.e `serverstorage["amount"] = 3`)

Thanks In Advance!

**EDIT:** Thanks @chucky for giving me that good answer, and finally getting me to acknowledge that back end existed.

**EDIT 2:** Fix gramar and clear up the question

Comment: To share data with other users you actually need to store them on a server. For a quick start I would suggest you looking into Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Comment: Date is a quite good shared variable, it won't be **exactly** the same, but should be good enough for any recreational purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you would need some kind of server side script that your javascript can call via an AJAX request to get the value of the cryptocurrency.

the server side script would either return a raw value or it would look up the value in a database or other storage system.

the implementation would be up to you, but a simple php file could return something like this:

```php
<?php
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');//make sure we have USD dollar sign
    $value = 3.0;//or get your value from where ever you need to
    $output = money_format('%.2n', $value);
    echo($output);  
?>
```

now in javascript you would make a request to your php script something like this:

```js
function getcurrencyvalue() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("currency").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "currency.php", true);//the GET request should be where you put the php file.
  xhttp.send();
}
```

and all that would be put into an html file (or what ever you're using):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Currency Test</title>
        <script src="currency.js"></script>
        <script>
            getcurrencyvalue();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Currency Value is:</h1>
        <div id="currency">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

after all that is setup then all you need to do is have your clients load that page and it'll always be the value that you return for multiple users.